# What is a dataset on z/OS?

Tags: file, dataset, zos

What is a dataset, described in terms familiar to someone that has used UNIX and Linux systems.

Comment: would appreciate some input on why this isn't a good question... I see some people don't like it but there is no reason why.

Comment: I edited the question - hopefully it's better now

Comment: You might want to read the [help/on-topic] page - this question does not seem to fit the community guidelines.  Asking for the advantages of A vs B is, in many cases is seen as either: a) seeking recommendations b) Highly opinion-based c) very contextual: i.e. answers vary depending on different scenarios/context.

Comment: ok. i reworded the question. I don't think the answer has any opinions in it as opposed to just facts, but I can understand why it might be considered so.

Comment: as you can see in the other answers, people are already saying things like 'if you look at it in a different way'... already tells you opinions are being expressed (which again, under a different POV or context, the answer changes slightly)

Comment: I see what you are saying. I reworded it to just ask what a dataset is, so that it isn't opinion-based.

Comment: Aside from what’s been stated already: this isn’t a programming question. Plus this is more of a documentation/information request (also off-topic)

Answer (score 8):

z/OS was (and is) designed for processing data very efficiently.
Depending on how your data is structured, and how your data is accessed, you can choose from many ways to store that data including a UNIX file system or a variety of data set  (often called dataset) formats.

The dataset existed on z/OS before UNIX like file systems were introduced in 1994 (with MVS/ESA 5.1). There are many types of dataset, but I will discuss 3:

- Partitioned Dataset Extended (abbreviated PDSE)
- Sequential Dataset
- Virtual Storage Access Method (abbreviated VSAM)

People used datasets for everything including source code, scripts, listings, object files, DLLs (shared libraries), and programs. And - also of course data.
Partitioned and Sequential datasets are common to use for everything except application data. VSAM works very well for data.

From an organization perspective, a PDSE is a simple one-level directory. The PDSE contains a set of members that can be accessed relatively independently. A sequential dataset is even simpler - it has no members and just contains data.

VSAM provides efficient access to data and has been optimized to work well for concurrent read and update access across many programs, running on many z/OS instances, in a parallel sysplex environment.

When working with VSAM (and datasets in general), perhaps the most important thing to understand is that access is by RECORD not STREAM. This makes it very efficient to seek to different locations by doing some basic math if every record is the same length (which we call a fixed length) at the expense of wasting some space, or to use variable length with an index file to maintain offsets into the dataset. While you can simulate this same capability in a file for variable length processing, it isn't something the file system is optimized for, and maintaining your own index for variable length concurrent update would be a lot of code to write (and try to get right).
Many applications today either work with data directly in VSAM datasets, or indirectly (by using a database product like Db2 which uses VSAM datasets in it's implementation).

Dataset naming requirements are quite restrictive. Names must be less than 44 characters, must be alpha-numeric upper-case, with a few additional characters called national characters, and are separated into 'qualifiers' that can be no more than 8 characters each, e.g.

FULTONM.MY.LISTING

is a valid dataset name but

FULTONM.MY.COBOLLISTING

is not, because COBOLLISTING is more than 8 characters.

There are literally dozens of dataset organizations and file format combinations. To learn more, start here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos-basic-skills?topic=zc-zos-storage-constructs-file-systems-data-sets-more

Comment: How is VSAM different than using a sql database like db2?

Comment: Isn't VSAM more like a nosql database like MongoDB?

Comment: I wrote it. What is stupid?

Comment: My apoligies, didn't mean to offend you. But for example this: "VSAM works very well for data." That doesn't mean anything, Every data set organisation and access method works well with data, provided it is suitable for the kind of access needed. Also this statement: "... understand is that access is by RECORD not STREAM. **This makes it very efficient to seek to different locations**...". It is not true in general. Except for VSAM Relative Record data sets, it is *not* possible to calculate the position or a record, and seek directly. VSAM is used very rarely by applications (except DB2).

Comment: My point on data was more that PDS’s and sequential datasets are not really good for data because they have no support for concurrent sysplex access and have no key support (ksds) built into them. They are better suited for source code and listings and config files. I should have worded it better. I was trying to creat a useful introduction. 
If I have fixed records it is trivial to seek to the Nth record very efficiently in record I/o. With standard byte steam files, unless you manually force fixed record length or have an index file you have to scan for newlines to find the nth record.

Comment: Regarding 'how is VSAM different than sql databases': VSAM provides the core building blocks for a database and you can build a database USING VSAM (Db2 does) but it requires A LOT of code since VSAM provides the primitives such as keyed sequential and relative record datasets

Comment: Regarding 'VSAM comparison to NOSQL database', I would have to say 'yes'. See: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=sharing-defining-accessing-vsam-rls-database (first sentence)

Comment: fwiw I wrote a blog awhile ago on VSAM as a simple key store: https://makingdeveloperslivesbetter.wordpress.com/2021/03/17/vsam-the-no-charge-z-os-db/

Answer (score 0):

If you think of z/OS datasets as residing in a z/OS file system then the various qualifiers on the dataset name could be considered directories in the file system.

For example:

SYS1.PARMLIB could be viewed as /sys1/parmlib just with a different annotation.

USERID.SOURCE.APP.REXX could be /userid/source/app/rexx

Just different ways of looking at things.

And with z/OS everything is EBCDIC - no differentiation between text or binary or some other encoding.

Comment: *And with z/OS everything is EBCDIC - no differentiation between text or binary or some other encoding.*: Rubbish. What lead you to that statement. Datasets on z/OS contain just what the programs or users write into. This can be text (in *any* encoding, *any* code page), this can be pure binary data (binary numbers, packed decimal numbers, etc.), or any combination of text and binary. As on any system, you need to understand how data records are built.

Comment: I agree with you - I'm just pointing out that instead of a / for *nix filesystems, in z/OS they use a . and you get effectively the same result. And the data on z/OS is in EBCDIC - that is the foundation. True it can be in other character sets but rarely is, it can be in binary as all load modules are, and can have binary or packed or ... fields, but it is all within the EBCDIC environment.

Comment: All true but you have to convert EBCDIC to the other formats with the base being EBCDIC.

Comment: You had to tell FTP to use binary transfer mode, otherwise your ASCII  text would have been converted to EBCDIC. It took an overt decision to make it other than EBCDIC.

Comment: You won. I have deleted my comments not to confuse people to much.